# How can i attach automatic image/s to container in a web page using webbrowser control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For now i can add text to the message for the title and body(content).
But now i want to attach automatic also files/images to the message.

This is a screenshot showing the message page and on the bottom the part of the attaching images.

You can attach images and videos. The red circle is where i click to add images.
The black circle is if i want to add video.
The yellow circle is the window/continer where i can drag&drop to the images.
If i click to add a video it should be a link like a yuotube video link.

[image: Screenshot]

When i make Inspect on the container where you need to drag and drop or to click and select images to attach i see this:

[image: Screenshot1]

This is my code now:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace AutomaticPosting
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        bool clickedAdd = false;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser2.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted;
        }

        private void WebBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
            {
                return;
            }

            HtmlElementCollection items1 = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("span");
            if (clickedAdd == false)
            {
                foreach (HtmlElement item in items1)
                {
                    if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "addMessage")
                    {
                        item.InvokeMember("click");
                        webBrowser2.DocumentCompleted += WebBrowser2_DocumentCompleted;
                        try
                        {
                            clickedAdd = true;
                            webBrowser2.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/addmsg/394");
                            break;
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            string myerr = ex.ToString();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void WebBrowser2_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Url.AbsoluteUri != webBrowser2.Url.AbsoluteUri)
            {
                return;
            }

            try
            {
                HtmlElementCollection items = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
                foreach (HtmlElement item in items)
                {
                    if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "elements")
                    {
                        webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_CKEditor1").InnerText = "What is the forecast please ?";//"עורך טקסט עשיר, ctl00_RightMainContent_CKEditor1";
                    }
                    if (item.GetAttribute("className") == "elements")
                    {
                        webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_txt_subject").InnerText = "אני מכונאי";
                    }
                }

                // cke_1_contents


                var div = webBrowser2.Document.GetElementById("ctl00_RightMainContent_submitAddress_p_submitButtom");
                if (div != null)
                {
                    var button = div.All.Cast<HtmlElement>().Where(x =>
                        !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.GetAttribute("className")) &&
                        x.GetAttribute("className").Contains("btn_send")).FirstOrDefault();
                    string ss = "";
                    if (button != null)
                        button.InvokeMember("click");
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show("Button not found.");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ee)
            {
                string exception = ee.ToString();
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.tapuz.co.il/forums/forumpage/394");
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have 0 experience in C# or .NET web development. But you can consider using base64 encoding. Because binary data sent from the browser is not something that will be easily portable across browsers.

Now since you can send text, you can send base64 encoded binary data.